# SQLCODE -1334 on DB2 when trying to connect using MicroStrategy

Tags: db2, microstrategy, sqlcode

I am wondering if anyone has ever encountered the following error when trying to connect to a DB2 database:

> Connect failed.
>
> Error type: Odbc error. Odbc operation attempted:
>
> SQLDriverConnect. [HY000:-1334: on SQLHANDLE] [MicroStrategy][ODBC DB2
>   Wire Protocol driver][DB2]Unknown error:  SQLCODE -1334

I have looked at the DB2 documentation and am unable to find the SQL code error. I can't figure out what's going on. Would I have to update or downgrade the ODBC drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 9.3.0 there is a bugfix for an issue related to version 9.2.1 and DB2 on Windows as you can see [here](https://resource.microstrategy.com/support/Authoring/DisplayTN.aspx?tnkey=40110&formatted=1)

Or simply you have the wrong configuration (i.e. database name) like the guy in [this discussion](https://resource.microstrategy.com/forum/replylistpage.aspx?id=33263).

Comment: Thanks - I can't make out why but the configuration that worked for an application using JDBC didn't work. It might be related to the cataloging issue mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what documentation you were looking at, but here goes:

```
$ db2 \? sql1334


SQL1334N  The database server or DB2 Connect server cannot be used to
      route a remote request to a second database server in this
      configuration.

Explanation: 

An attempt was made to route a request through a database server node or
DB2 Connect server node using an unsupported combination of client and
target database server, or from a non-LUW DRDA client to a DRDA target
database through a LUW database server or DB2 Connect server. The
request must be routed directly from the client to the node on which the
target database is running.

User response: 

Uncatalog the database at the client machine and then catalog the
database specifying the node on which the database actually resides.
Ensure that the node is also cataloged.
```

Comment: Thanks! Issue has been resolved after updating my configuration. Might be related to the way things are catalog.

Comment: Perhaps it's related to using the 3rd party ODBC drivers that Microstrategy includes, as opposed to using the native DB2 Client.